# Avoid new line after \paragraph{Blah blah} command

Tags: sections-paragraphs

My corporate template bolds the text provided to the `\paragraph{Blah blah}` command and adds a new line.  I want the bolding, but I don't want the new line.  Too many paragraphs, and it just uses up so much vertical spacing.  I want the text to continue unbolded right after the bolded `Blah blah`.

Eventually, I want to use the `\nameref` and `\pageref` commands, targeting a label that immediately follows the above `\paragraph` command.  But I first need to prevent the `\paragraph` command from ending with a new line.

Is there a way to do this without diving into the corporate template files?

My corporate template is not post-able, and I haven't posted my document's top-level LaTeX file because it requires too many parameters for the corporate template.  However, here is a *normal* LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nameref}
\begin{document}

\paragraph{First paragraph heading} \label{pr_1}
First paragraph body.

\paragraph{Second paragraph heading}
Second paragraph body.

\verb+\nameref{pr_1}:+ \nameref{pr_1}

\verb+\pageref{pr_1}:+ \pageref{pr_1}

\end{document}
```

The result shows the desired absence of a new line:

[image]

Here is the middle section of the code that I transplanted into my report

```
\paragraph{First paragraph heading} \label{pr_1}
First paragraph body.

\paragraph{Second paragraph heading}
Second paragraph body.

\verb+\nameref{pr_1}:+ \nameref{pr_1}

\verb+\pageref{pr_1}:+ \pageref{pr_1}
```

The result is as follows, showing the undesirable new line:

[image]

Comment: Answer to your final question: no.

Comment: `\paragraph` is a 4th level section heading after subsubsubsection, do you have so many subsubsubsub sections? If you just want a bold word at the start of a paragraph you can use `\textbf{My} paragraph starts here...`

Comment: If I do that, how can I attach a label to the text so that I can use `\nameref` and `\pageref`?

Comment: pageref but not nameref would work, but if you want tighter integration you need to show an example document we can not tell you how to change code we can not see. In the standard classes paragraph does not start a new line

Comment: I added code examples and results.  I also found a work-around: Use `\subparagraph`.  It's more in line with the muted highlighting of the argument text anyway.  Thanks.

Comment: There must be some kind of redefinition for the paragraph environment in between. At first you were getting correct results (without newline), then the \paragraph environment was redefined, then you started getting a newline.

Comment: You don't need to dive into the template file to redefine the new paragraph command.  But diving into the template file to see how it defines the new paragraph command would be helpful.

Comment: I found the `*.cls` file in which `\newcommand\paragraph{...}` occurs, but with all the punctuation, it looks like "line noise".  It also contains corporate-specific identifiers, so I don't feel comfortable posting it.